# Implementing Configured LoggerFactory with Dependency Injection (DI) in Different Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been exploring the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging documentation and found examples for [configuring a LoggerFactory using code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#configure-logging-with-code). I came across patterns like:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(static builder =>
{
    builder
        .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
        .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
        .AddFilter("LoggingConsoleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
        .AddConsole();
});

ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
logger.LogDebug("Hello {Target}", "Everyone");
```

And:

```
var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(config =>
{
    config.AddConsole();
    config.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
}).CreateLogger("Program");
```

However, I'm interested in utilizing this configured `loggerFactory` via Dependency Injection (DI) in other classes, yet I couldn't find an example illustrating this approach in the documentation.

I'm seeking guidance or an example demonstrating how to use the configured `loggerFactory` with DI, allowing me to inject the ILogger instance into multiple classes throughout the application. Any insights, code examples, or suggestions on how to achieve this within a broader context would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need the factory in you classes? What the actual task you've trying to solve? If it's just for logging, you inject `ILogger<T>`, not the factory. Factory will create appropriate logger under the hood for you.

Comment: I used LoggerFactory because that's the pattern that I see in the examples that I've learned from.  Could you point me at a complete example that configures a LoggerFactory and then injects an ILogger<T>?

Comment: [net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly](https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly/)

Comment: This is what you use when you’re not using DI.

Comment: `builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();`

Comment: @qiang-fu do you mean 
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoggerFactory, loggerFactory>();

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing - for now anyway

### Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddGoogleCloudConsole(options => {
   options.IncludeScopes = true;
   options.TraceGoogleCloudProjectId = "saql-cloud-run";
});

var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}";
builder.WebHost.UseUrls(url);

var app = builder.Build();

// logging in out flow
app.Logger.LogInformation($"EnvironmentName: {app.Environment.EnvironmentName}"); // Development

app.MapGet("/", (ILogger<Program> logger) => {
    // logging in endpoint
    logger.LogInformation("In /");
    return Results.Ok("Hello World");
});
```

### MyService.cs

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{

    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyService (ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<MySettings> options)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>();
    }

}
```

I think I'll also try the *How to Use the Logging API from Everywhere* approach shown in https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly

Thanks everyone for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a customloggerfactory class and make a method to return the configured loggerfactory.
MyLoggerFactory.cs

```
    public class MyLoggerFactory
    {
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(static builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                    .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                    .AddFilter("LoggingConsoleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
                    .AddConsole();
            });

            return loggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyLoggerFactory>();
```

Then You could use by DI like this:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TestController(MyLoggerFactory myLoggerFactory)
        {
            this._logger = myLoggerFactory.CreateLogger("TestController");
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("custome logger logged information");
        }
    }
```